# Can I submit an application developed for iphone OS 2.0 to the app store?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have developed application for iPhone OS 2.0.  Will I be able to submit it to app store? Will Apple approve my application...or do I need to create the app for 3.0 also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no problem with this. You should set your target's `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` build setting to '2.0'.

When you submit your application there's a check box 'Tested on IPhone OS 3.0', which you should only check if you're sure that your app works on 3.0 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Apple will test your application on an OS 3.0 device. Most apps developed for OS 2.0 will run fine on OS 3.0. However, in some cases it won't and your app will be rejected.
It is recommendable to try your 2.0 binary on a 3.0 device before submitting.